# Use "li" or "li a" for styling "a" inside "li"

Tags: css, styling

Suppose the following HTML:

```html
<li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</li>
```

Which one of the CSS styles is correct to set the font-size?

```css
li {
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

```css
li a {
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many CSS styles are inherited from a parent to its children, font-size included.
If you imagine this hierarchy as a tree, the general rule is to **apply styles as high (parent) as possible** but **as low (children) as necessary**. Styles should also be as **general as possible** (meaning low selector count).

In your case this means that if you only want to select the ‘a’s inside ‘li’s you should use the second rule. If you want the font-size of all ‘li’s to be 12px you may apply the style to the `li` or `ul, ol` or even the body or an outer container.

Answer (score 1):

For your simplified example, either one will work. The first would affect all list items, though, whereas the second would only affect **links** *within* list items. Which one is appropriate depends on whether/how you're using list items elsewhere in the code.

Comment: So it does respect the CSS guidelines and syntax? I mean let's say the items on the list are all links. Which is more appropriate in this example?

Comment: @power2b If you want to style links, target `a`. If you want to target list items, target `li`. If you want to target links inside list items, target `li a`. Ultimately, which is most appropriate is up to **you** based on the code you're building.